What's going on with go's function preludes on arm64?
I don't understand what's going on here with this function prelude.
Here's a function from the go runtime that should be present in a hello world program.
0000000100064da0 <_runtime.osinit_hack_trampoline.abi0>:
100064da0: f81f0ffe     str x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
100064da4: f81f83fd     stur    x29, [sp, #-0x8]
100064da8: d10023fd     sub x29, sp, #0x8
100064dac: aa1f03e0     mov x0, xzr
100064db0: 9400a01f     bl  0x10008ce2c <_xpc_date_create_from_current+0x10008ce2c>
100064db4: 9400a021     bl  0x10008ce38 <_xpc_date_create_from_current+0x10008ce38>
100064db8: a97ffbfd     ldp x29, x30, [sp, #-0x8]
100064dbc: 910043ff     add sp, sp, #0x10
100064dc0: d65f03c0     ret

The frame pointer (x29) is pointing to 8 bytes past the stack pointer.
A C prelude output by clang looks something like this
sub sp, sp, #32
stp x29, x30, [sp, #16]             ; 16-byte Folded Spill
add x29, sp, #16

This will immediately clobber the frame pointer saved at 100064da4 when it calls a C function at  100064db0.  Why isn't this a problem?   What am I missing?
(go 1.22.6, Mac OS, arm64)
edit: I think this is actually just invalid output from go.   The chain of frame pointers really is getting clobbered and backtrace tools like lldb can no longer follow the stack.  I made an issue on github for it

Okay I think I see your problem but the x29 value is unrelated. The issue is the [sp, #-0x8] which is accessing below the stack pointer.

Yeah, this looks broken. Normally the pair of x29, x30 is spilled to an 0x10-byte aligned address. In this case, x29 is at -0x8 and x30 is at +0x0, which would work as far as frame pointers go, except that x29 is stored outside of the allocated stack space. This really feels like the first three instructions there all got 0x8 subtracted somewhere in the compiler pipeline when they shouldn't have.
